# Can't able to do start testing in(Internal Tester) in Testflight

Tags: ios, swift, build, testflight

I'm getting Below Error while click start testing Button in Testflight,

"This version can’t be tested because you have reached the maximum number of apps allowed for testing at once."

I don't know why this is happened,

Advice me to fix this issue

Screenshot: [Here is the Screenshot for your reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haHmI.png)

Comment: how many apps do you have in TestFlight right now?

Comment: May be More than 100 app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This version can’t be tested because you have reached the maximum number of apps allowed for testing at once

**From apple :**

`Your internal team, Each app can be tested by up to 25 members of your team who have been assigned the Developer or Admin role in iTunes Connect. Each member can test on up to 10 devices.`
Once you’re ready, you can invite up to 2,000 users who do not need to be part of your development organization to beta test an app that you intend for public release on the App Store. A review is required for new versions of your app that contain significant changes. **Up to 100 apps can be tested at a time, internally or externally**.

Comment: Thanks Hasan , Up to 100 apps can be tested at a time, internally or externally. I fix it

Comment: Nazmul, where did you find the info on the maximum number of apps that can be tested?

Comment: @ForestKunecke please check this https://developer.apple.com/testflight/

Comment: @NazmulHasan Ah, it says it right there! I did not notice that before